# Meaning of $(OutDir)

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, environment-variables

I was looking in the properties of my visual studio project and saw the following:

```
$(OutDir)\$(ProjectName).exe
```

I was curious how does visual studio know the value of outdir and how can i see this value. Moreover, which language is this, eg C#, python? In other words, what language is `$(OutDir)\$(ProjectName).exe` written in

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`$(OutDir)` is a Visual Studio Build Property Macro.

You can see the values of macros using the *Macros >>* button in many Properties dialogs.

For instance, in *Properties->General->Output Directory*, click the dropdown in the value text box, choose *Edit...*, and in the resulting dialog, click the *Macros >>* button. This will give you a list of all the macros and their current values.

`$(OutputDir)` should be set to the output directory for the current configuration, e.g. `$(SolutionDir)/$(Configuration)\`.

Note that your Windows environment variables are imported as Build Property macros in your project, so in the marco list you'll see, e.g. `$(Path)`, `$(HOME)`, `$(TEMP)`.

Comment: How do you see the macros for environment variables?

Comment: @Programmer they're also available as macros like: $(Path), and should be visible in the same list mentioned in the answer. See my edit.

Comment: i meant see the value of all env variables, not necessay those in vs

Comment: @Programmer are you asking how to iterate over environment variables from within your program?

Comment: No, I am just asking that is there a place in my comp that i can see all the env varaibles.

Comment: @Programmer I see. Yes, from DOS/cmd you can always type `set` to get a list. You can also Right-Click on the _Computer_ icon on your desktop, select _Properties_, and in the new window click _Advanced System Settings` in the sidebar on the left, then in the _Advanced_ tab, click the _Environment Variables_ button.

Comment: I couldn't find where to go to click 'Properties' in 'Properties->General->Output Directory'.

Comment: Hi @TolaOdejayi: I'm looking at VS 2012. For instance, I right-click my solution in the _Solution Explorer_ and select _Properties_. Then I click the _Build Events_ button and in the resulting dialog I click _Macros >>_. This is one place, there may be others.

Comment: Any suggestion for multiple target frameworks?
I use ``<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;netcoreapp3.1</TargetFrameworks>`` and $(OutDir) and $(TargetFramework) are empty while ``$(TargetFrameworks)`` __(plural)__ in the path just give me "netstandard2.0"

Comment: @Alex75 sorry I won't have much to offer: haven't gone any deeper into this configuration since this answer

Comment: How would we programmatically print this? This can be useful because the macros may be defined differently on our machine vs another user's machine.

Comment: Hi @Denis. Note that this answer is pretty dated and refers to VS 2012. Let me make sure I understand your question: where would you like to print macro variables? In the output window during a project build?

Comment: @pb2q to output them both during the build, on the output screen, and to print during execution of the program. This is because I'm experiencing a lot of issues with files not being found on a build system that the macros are not setup the same way as my machine so want to confirm the files (includes and files used during unit test execution) are being looked for at the right place.

Comment: @Denis just taking a stab at it here, can't actually verify in VS. 1) print in output window: as I recall you can do something like DOS style commands in Pre/Post-Build steps. So try creating a Post-Build step with e.g. `ECHO $(OutputDir)`. 2) print as part of program output: this will depend on your environment/language. But if these macros are environment vars as suggested in my answer, then using e.g. C APIs, look into the `getenv` and related functions. I'd also recommend creating a new top-level question with your specifics here on SO

Answer (score 7):

These macros are documented by Microsoft in the topic [Macros for Build Commands and Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs.aspx). (That link is for Visual Studio 2015.)

Answer (score 1):

Those are MSBuild properties. They can be user defined or environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the file    `the_name_of_your_prog.VCPROJ`  (in the example : ttfmfc)

and replace :  `$(SolutionDir)$(ConfigurationName)`   and `$(SolutionDir)` by F:\debug
(F:\debug is in a ramdisk, or any other foler)

In the example below, only debug configuration has been changed : 
visual studio 2008 
replace every [ by (lower than sign) and ] by (greater than sign)

```
[?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?]

[VisualStudioProject
    ProjectType="Visual C++"
    Version="9.00"
    Name="ttsmfc"
    ProjectGUID="{0B52B3C5-7AD5-4780-92E9-98674E486261}"
    RootNamespace="ttsmfc"
    Keyword="MFCProj"
    TargetFrameworkVersion="196613"
    ]

    [Platforms]

        [Platform
            Name="Win32"
        /]

    [/Platforms]

    [ToolFiles]

    [/ToolFiles]

    [Configurations]

        [Configuration
            Name="Debug|Win32"
            OutputDirectory="F:\Debug"
            IntermediateDirectory="F:\Debug"
            ConfigurationType="1"
            UseOfMFC="2"
            CharacterSet="1"
            ]

            [Tool
                Name="VCPreBuildEventTool"
            /]

            [Tool
                Name="VCCustomBuildTool"
            /]

            [Tool
                Name="VCXMLDataGeneratorTool"
            /]

            [Tool
                Name="VCWebServiceProxyGeneratorTool"
            /]

            [Tool
                Name="VCMIDLTool"
                PreprocessorDefinitions="_DEBUG"
                MkTypLibCompatible="true"
                SuppressStartupBanner="true"
                TargetEnvironment="1"
                TypeLibraryName="f:\Debug/ort.tlb"
                HeaderFileName=""
            /]

            [Tool
                Name="VCCLCompilerTool"
                Optimization="0"
                PreprocessorDefinitions="WIN32;_WINDOWS;_DEBUG"
                MinimalRebuild="true"
                BasicRuntimeChecks="3"
                RuntimeLibrary="3"
                UsePrecompiledHeader="2"
                PrecompiledHeaderThrough="stdafx.h"
                PrecompiledHeaderFile="F:\Debug/ort.pch"
                AssemblerListingLocation="F:\Debug/"
                ObjectFile="F:\Debug/"
                ProgramDataBaseFileName="F:\Debug/"
                WarningLevel="3"
                DebugInformationFormat="4"
            /]

            [Tool
                Name="VCManagedResourceCompilerTool"
            /]

            [Tool
                Name="VCResourceCompilerTool"
                PreprocessorDefinitions="_DEBUG"
                Culture="1036"
                AdditionalIncludeDirectories="$(IntDir)"
            /]

            [Tool
                Name="VCPreLinkEventTool"
            /]

            [Tool
                Name="VCLinkerTool"
                AdditionalDependencies="winmm.lib"
                LinkIncremental="2"
                GenerateDebugInformation="true"
                SubSystem="2"
                TargetMachine="1"
            /]

            [Tool
                Name="VCALinkTool"
            /]

            [Tool
                Name="VCManifestTool"
            /]

            [Tool
                Name="VCXDCMakeTool"
            /]

            [Tool
                Name="VCBscMakeTool"
            /]

            [Tool
                Name="VCFxCopTool"
            /]

            [Tool
                Name="VCAppVerifierTool"
            /]

            [Tool
                Name="VCPostBuildEventTool"
            /]

        [/Configuration]

        [Configuration
            Name="Release|Win32"
            OutputDirectory="$(SolutionDir)$(ConfigurationName)"
            IntermediateDirectory="$(ConfigurationName)"
            ConfigurationType="1"
            UseOfMFC="2"
            CharacterSet="1"
            WholeProgramOptimization="1"
            ]

            [Tool
                Name="VCPreBuildEventTool"
            /]

            [Tool
                Name="VCCustomBuildTool"
            /]

            [Tool
                Name="VCXMLDataGeneratorTool"
            /]

            [Tool
                Name="VCWebServiceProxyGeneratorTool"
            /]

            [Tool
                Name="VCMIDLTool"
                PreprocessorDefinitions="NDEBUG"
                MkTypLibCompatible="false"
                ValidateParameters="true"
            /]

            [Tool
                Name="VCCLCompilerTool"
                Optimization="2"
                EnableIntrinsicFunctions="true"
                PreprocessorDefinitions="WIN32;_WINDOWS;NDEBUG"
                MinimalRebuild="false"
                RuntimeLibrary="2"
                EnableFunctionLevelLinking="true"
                UsePrecompiledHeader="2"
                WarningLevel="3"
                DebugInformationFormat="3"
            /]

            [Tool
                Name="VCManagedResourceCompilerTool"
            /]

            [Tool
                Name="VCResourceCompilerTool"
                PreprocessorDefinitions="NDEBUG"
                Culture="1036"
                AdditionalIncludeDirectories="$(IntDir)"
            /]

            [Tool
                Name="VCPreLinkEventTool"
            /]

            [Tool
                Name="VCLinkerTool"
                AdditionalDependencies="winmm.lib"
                LinkIncremental="1"
                GenerateDebugInformation="true"
                SubSystem="2"
                OptimizeReferences="2"
                EnableCOMDATFolding="2"
                TargetMachine="1"
            /]

            [Tool
                Name="VCALinkTool"
            /]

            [Tool
                Name="VCManifestTool"
            /]

            [Tool
                Name="VCXDCMakeTool"
            /]

            [Tool
                Name="VCBscMakeTool"
            /]

            [Tool
                Name="VCFxCopTool"
            /]

            [Tool
                Name="VCAppVerifierTool"
            /]

            [Tool
                Name="VCPostBuildEventTool"
            /]

        [/Configuration]

    [/Configurations]

    [References]

    [/References]

    [Files]

        [Filter
            Name="Fichiers sources"
            Filter="cpp;c;cc;cxx;def;odl;idl;hpj;bat;asm;asmx"
            UniqueIdentifier="{4FC737F1-C7A5-4376-A066-2A32D752A2FF}"
            ]

            [File
                RelativePath=".\Buffer.cpp"
                ]

            [/File]

            [File
                RelativePath=".\ChangeRes.cpp"
                ]

            [/File]

            [File
                RelativePath=".\errorprint.cpp"
                ]

            [/File]

            [File
                RelativePath=".\MainFrm.cpp"
                ]

            [/File]

            [File
                RelativePath=".\Mot.cpp"
                ]

            [/File]

            [File
                RelativePath=".\Pipe.cpp"
                ]

            [/File]

            [File
                RelativePath=".\PtrFifo.cpp"
                ]

            [/File]

            [File
                RelativePath=".\Reco.cpp"
                ]

            [/File]

            [File
                RelativePath=".\SoundBase.cpp"
                ]

            [/File]

            [File
                RelativePath=".\SoundFile.cpp"
                ]

            [/File]

            [File
                RelativePath=".\SoundIn.cpp"
                ]

            [/File]

            [File
                RelativePath=".\SoundOut.cpp"
                ]

            [/File]

            [File
                RelativePath=".\stdafx.cpp"
                ]

                [FileConfiguration
                    Name="Debug|Win32"
                    ]

                    [Tool
                        Name="VCCLCompilerTool"
                        UsePrecompiledHeader="1"
                    /]

                [/FileConfiguration]

                [FileConfiguration
                    Name="Release|Win32"
                    ]

                    [Tool
                        Name="VCCLCompilerTool"
                        UsePrecompiledHeader="1"
                    /]

                [/FileConfiguration]

            [/File]

            [File
                RelativePath=".\ttsmfc.cpp"
                ]

            [/File]

            [File
                RelativePath=".\ttsmfcDoc.cpp"
                ]

            [/File]

            [File
                RelativePath=".\ttsmfcView.cpp"
                ]

            [/File]

            [File
                RelativePath=".\vegView.cpp"
                ]

            [/File]

        [/Filter]

        [Filter
            Name="Fichiers d&apos;en-tête"
            Filter="h;hpp;hxx;hm;inl;inc;xsd"
            UniqueIdentifier="{93995380-89BD-4b04-88EB-625FBE52EBFB}"
            ]

            [File
                RelativePath=".\Buffer.h"
                ]

            [/File]

            [File
                RelativePath=".\errorprint.h"
                ]

            [/File]

            [File
                RelativePath=".\fister.h"
                ]

            [/File]

            [File
                RelativePath=".\MainFrm.h"
                ]

            [/File]

            [File
                RelativePath=".\Mot.h"
                ]

            [/File]

            [File
                RelativePath=".\Pipe.h"
                ]

            [/File]

            [File
                RelativePath=".\PtrFifo.h"
                ]

            [/File]

            [File
                RelativePath=".\Reco.h"
                ]

            [/File]

            [File
                RelativePath=".\Resource.h"
                ]

            [/File]

            [File
                RelativePath=".\SoundBase.h"
                ]

            [/File]

            [File
                RelativePath=".\SoundFile.h"
                ]

            [/File]

            [File
                RelativePath=".\SoundIn.h"
                ]

            [/File]

            [File
                RelativePath=".\SoundOut.h"
                ]

            [/File]

            [File
                RelativePath=".\stdafx.h"
                ]

            [/File]

            [File
                RelativePath=".\targetver.h"
                ]

            [/File]

            [File
                RelativePath=".\ttsmfc.h"
                ]

            [/File]

            [File
                RelativePath=".\ttsmfcDoc.h"
                ]

            [/File]

            [File
                RelativePath=".\ttsmfcView.h"
                ]

            [/File]

            [File
                RelativePath=".\type.h"
                ]

            [/File]

            [File
                RelativePath=".\vegView.h"
                ]

            [/File]

        [/Filter]

        [Filter
            Name="Fichiers de ressources"
            Filter="rc;ico;cur;bmp;dlg;rc2;rct;bin;rgs;gif;jpg;jpeg;jpe;resx;tiff;tif;png;wav"
            UniqueIdentifier="{67DA6AB6-F800-4c08-8B7A-83BB121AAD01}"
            ]

            [File
                RelativePath=".\res\Toolbar.bmp"
                ]

            [/File]

            [File
                RelativePath=".\res\ttsmfc.ico"
                ]

            [/File]

            [File
                RelativePath=".\ttsmfc.rc"
                ]

            [/File]

            [File
                RelativePath=".\res\ttsmfc.rc2"
                ]

            [/File]

            [File
                RelativePath=".\res\ttsmfcDoc.ico"
                ]

            [/File]

        [/Filter]

        [File
            RelativePath=".\ReadMe.txt"
            ]

        [/File]

    [/Files]

    [Globals]

        [Global
            Name="RESOURCE_FILE"
            Value="ttsmfc.rc"
        /]

    [/Globals]

[/VisualStudioProject]
```

Comment: This information seems to concern a vc2008 and this is quite out of date for more recent versions of Visual Studio.