# How do I use a localized PostBuildEvent in an environment with multiple collaborators?

Tags: git, visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2015

I have a project which has the following `PostBuildEvent`:

```
<PostBuildEvent>
 if exist Diagnostic.nuspec 
 if exist "$(SolutionDir)\packages\NuGet.CommandLine.2.8.2\tools\NuGet.exe"
 "$(SolutionDir)\packages\NuGet.CommandLine.2.8.2\tools\NuGet.exe" 
 pack Diagnostic.nuspec 
 -OutputDirectory "C:\Users\jeroen\Google Drive\NugetLocal\VSDiagnostics"
</PostBuildEvent>
```

Here, the `OutPutDirectory` is obviously local to my own installation. The default value is `.`.

This configuration is stored in the project's `.csproj` file which also keeps track of things like references to other assemblies and the files in the project.

For this reason I can't simply ignore the file in git or none of my other changes to `.csproj` would go through.

Is there any way I can keep my localized `PostBuildEvent` without imposing it on other collaborators?

Comment: Possible XY problem? Why do you want this output to an external directory? Have you considered doing this only for the `Release` build?

Comment: I have a local NuGet feed pointed at that directory because I also have other projects that point to that local feed. If I would leave everything in the default directory of the project, that would mean I'd need a different local feed for each project. I'm not sure how only doing this for release builds would solve it though.

Comment: Your collaborators shouldn't have a need to build a release. You're the maintainer, so you're the one doing the release builds.

Comment: Set an environment variable and also give it a default value.

Comment: @LexLi I'm unsure how that would alleviate the pain. That would actually make it pretty hard on collaborators. Then they'd have to set up the environment variable too. I'm of the opinion that the entire project should be able to be cloned and built. The right thing to do here is to add a new local nuget feed.

Comment: @LexLi: I've been playing around with that idea but can't seem to get it to work. Do I understand you correctly if you mean that I can define an environment variable on user-account level and use that in the csproj file? I don't want to set my custom path in the configuration file or I'd be stuck with the same issue having to check that in. Could you elaborate on that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it through setting a user-account level environment variable and depending on that, use it or use the default.

I simply swapped the original `PostBuildEvent` and surrounding `PropertyGroup` with this:

```
<Choose>
    <When Condition=" $(NUGETLOCAL) != '' ">
        <PropertyGroup>
            <PostBuildEvent>if exist Diagnostic.nuspec if exist "$(SolutionDir)\packages\NuGet.CommandLine.2.8.2\tools\NuGet.exe" "$(SolutionDir)\packages\NuGet.CommandLine.2.8.2\tools\NuGet.exe" pack Diagnostic.nuspec -OutputDirectory $(NUGETLOCAL)</PostBuildEvent>
            <RunPostBuildEvent>OnOutputUpdated</RunPostBuildEvent>
        </PropertyGroup>
    </When>
    <Otherwise>
        <PropertyGroup>
            <PostBuildEvent>if exist Diagnostic.nuspec if exist "$(SolutionDir)\packages\NuGet.CommandLine.2.8.2\tools\NuGet.exe" "$(SolutionDir)\packages\NuGet.CommandLine.2.8.2\tools\NuGet.exe" pack Diagnostic.nuspec -OutputDirectory .</PostBuildEvent>
            <RunPostBuildEvent>OnOutputUpdated</RunPostBuildEvent>
        </PropertyGroup>
    </Otherwise>
</Choose>
```

The environment variable is set as `NUGETLOCAL` with value `"C:\Users\jeroen\Google Drive\NugetLocal\VSDiagnostics"` (including accents). If the variable isn't set it will use the default directory and the user has the option to define his own at anytime he wants.

The code is probably not as pretty as it can be so let me know if you see an improvement.

I elaborated on this [here](http://www.vannevel.net/2015/06/22/generating-a-nuget-package-in-a-localized-directory-on-each-build/).

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in the comments, I think this should only be done for `Release` builds. The action could be skipped entirely unless it's being built in the `Release` configuration by leveraging the `ConfigurationName` Macro.

```
if $(ConfigurationName) == Release (
   if exist Diagnostic.nuspec 
   if exist "$(SolutionDir)\packages\NuGet.CommandLine.2.8.2\tools\NuGet.exe"
   "$(SolutionDir)\packages\NuGet.CommandLine.2.8.2\tools\NuGet.exe" 
   pack Diagnostic.nuspec 
   -OutputDirectory "C:\Users\jeroen\Google Drive\NugetLocal\VSDiagnostics"
)
```

Here's [the list of all the available Macros](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs.aspx). I also understand that [all Environment variables are imported as macros](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11074743/3198973), so you might be able to come up with something a little more elegant based on the user profile and the existence of the subdirectory.

---

Upon further thought, you could use a standard environment variable, `USERPROFILE` and just check to see if the path exists.

```
   if exist "$(USERPROFILE)\Google Drive\NugetLocal\VSDiagnostics"(
       if exist Diagnostic.nuspec 
       if exist "$(SolutionDir)\packages\NuGet.CommandLine.2.8.2\tools\NuGet.exe"
       "$(SolutionDir)\packages\NuGet.CommandLine.2.8.2\tools\NuGet.exe" 
       pack Diagnostic.nuspec 
       -OutputDirectory "$(USERPROFILE)\Google Drive\NugetLocal\VSDiagnostics"
   )
```

This does have some limitations though. It will only work on Windows. [Linux uses a different variable for the user profile path.](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html)

Comment: I will use this as a last resort because it would still impose a restriction on other collaborators. But it's still a good workaround.

Comment: Updated my answer to contain another possible solution. (Of course, extract a variable for the duplicated string)