# Where does VS save an environment variable like $(outdir)?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

Where does Visual Studio save an environment variable like "$(OutDir)"?

I don't see anything resembling "OutDir" in the command line.

Comment: Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you changed the "Output Directory" setting of your project, it is stored in the project's .vcxproj file.  Just try it, change the setting, save the project and have a look-see with a text editor:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <LinkIncremental>true</LinkIncremental>
    <OutDir>Example</OutDir>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

I changed the setting to "Example".

If you did not change the setting then MSBuild computes the value of the property (aka macro).  Pretty visible from the IDE, it glues the values of $(SolutionDir) and $(Configuration) together.

Those properties in turn are set by the IDE, based on the platform target and the configuration you have selected in the Build > Configuration Manager dialog.  If you build from the command line then you use MSBuild's /property option to select what you want to build.

Note how the environment plays no role at all.  If you *need* an environment variable because you are running some other kind of build tool then you'd do so by using the SET command in a pre- or post-build event.  Like:

```
  SET outdir="$(OutDir)"
```

Using double-quotes to avoid trouble with pathnames that contain a space.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you assuming they're saved? They're not; they exist solely within the build process

Comment: They are saved in the input to the MSBuild system (.vcxproj in this case, probably). What makes you assume they wouldn't be saved somewhere?

Answer (score -1):

these ar basically macros ; you can find the output directory in : `Properties->General->Output Directory` 
For more info check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074717/meaning-of-outdir)

Comment: Completely misses the question.